# How do i make my simple php form go to my html page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a simple PHP code and I want it to redirect it to my HTML page but I don't know how to do that? any help? (i don't use MySQL btw)

```
I have attached the code below
https://jsfiddle.net/7ta2jyqv/
```

I just want it to redirect to another page that I have created but I looked at tutorials and none of them worked

Does anyone have a simple code I can use??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please add the code you have tried to your post. This will make it easier for SO contributors to assist you. Please visit SO Help Center and the guidelines on adding a 'Minimal, Reproducible Example' >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try my code its very simple, first you make file called index.php
and bellow the code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["button"])){
    header("Location:redirect.html");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Click to redirect!</button> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

after that you make file called redirect.html
below the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redirected</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Your page finish to redirect ^_^</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

open your index.php on browser, in http://localhost/yourFolder/index.php

after that produce image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHcn8.png)

then just click the button, you will be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirect Form To a Particular Page On Submit - Demo Preview</title>
<meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots">
<link href='css/redirect_form.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!--== Include CSS File Here ==-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="first">
<h2>Redirect Form To a Particular Page On Submit using PHP</h2>
<form action="redirect_form.php" id="#form" method="post" name="#form">
<label>Name :</label>
<input id="name" name="name" placeholder='Your Name' type='text'>
<label>Email :</label>
<input id="email" name="email" placeholder='Valid Email Address' type='text'>
<label>Contact :</label>
<input id="contact" name="contact" placeholder='Contact' type='text'>
<label>Address:</label>
<input id="address" name="address" placeholder='Address' type='text' value="">
<input id='btn' name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit'>
<!---- Including PHP File Here ---->
<?php
include "include/redirect.php";
?>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in php for submiting form use it:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
if($name !=''&& $email !=''&& $contact !=''&& $address !='')
{
//  To redirect form on a particular page
header("Location:https://www.formget.com/app/");
}
else{
?><span><?php echo "Please fill all fields.....!!!!!!!!!!!!";?></span> <?php
}
}
?>
```

Remember it is only an example.  the header function helps redirect in php.
check this link: https://www.formget.com/how-to-redirect-a-url-php-form/